# Haskell list comprehension - list of all list splits

Tags: list, haskell

I've just wanted to write a function `splits` that takes a list `l` and returns a list of tuples that contain all possible ways to split `l`.

So it should work like this:

```
splits "Hello"
[("","Hello"),("H","ello"),("He","llo"),("Hel","lo"),("Hell","o"),("Hello","")]
```

**Implementation 1** What I wrote is this:

```
splits l = [(x,y) | i <- [0 ..length l], x <- take i l, y <- drop i l]
```

which gives

```
[('H','e'),('H','l'),('H','l'),('H','o'),('H','l'),('H','l'),('H','o'),
 ('e','l'),('e','l'),('e','o'),
 ('H','l'),('H','o'),
 ('e','l'),('e','o'),
 ('l','l'),('l','o'),
 ('H','o'),('e','o'),('l','o'),('l','o')]
```

**Implementation 2** The correct solution is

```
splits l = [(take i l, drop i l) | i <- [0 ..length l]]
```

**Question**: Why are implementation 1 and implementation 2 doing different things? What's going on in implementation 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key observation is what the statement `x <- list` does in the first version.
Let us look at a bit different example

```
[i | i <-[1..3]] => [1,2,3]
```

since `String = [Char]` one has

```
[c | c <- "Word"] => "Word" or equivalently ['W','o','r','d']
```

so we could correct your first version a teensy tiny bit and get the latter

```
splits l = [(x,y) | i <- [0 ..length l], x <- [take i l], y <- [drop i l]]
```

but still I have to say this is rather unidiomatic and a better solution in my eyes would be using a recursive function.

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
splits xx = splits' [] ([],xx)
  where splits' :: [([a],[a])]-> ([a],[a]) -> [([a],[a])]
        splits' acc xs@(_,[]) = reverse (xs:acc)
        splits' acc (xs,y:ys) = let xs' = (xs++[y],ys)
                                in splits' (xs':acc) xs'
```

or with higher order functions

```
splits :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
splits xx = zipWith splitAt [0..(length xx)] (repeat xx)
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand. I forgot that `take i l` is a list and `x <- [take i l]` will go through all elements and not simply assign the value. Thank you (+1 and accept).